# Store Metadata in XML Schema

Tags: xsd, metadata

i need to store additional metadata in a schema.

simplified:

```
<xs:schema>
    <xs:complexType name="CustomType" m:Representation="BlaBla">...</xs:complexTyp>
</xs:schema>
```

is it possible?

i have seen somthing like that in ms-datasets they use an additional an attribute "msprop".
but i've to see the source of urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop

Comment: Can you make your question a little clearer?  It seems like an interesting one, if it can be made clearer.  The short answer is yes,  you can store metadata in XML and control it with a schema.  But maybe that's not your real question.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using `xsd:appinfo` for that purpose. This can contain any XML content:

```
<xs:schema>
    <xs:complexType name="CustomType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
               <representation>BlaBla</representation>
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```